# Will Eclipse IDE 3.6.2 work just fine with OpenJDK Java 1.6?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have to turn my hand to a bit of Java/Tomcat and GNU C development. Will the current version of Eclipse (3.6.2 Helios) work just fine with the following configuration?:

- OpenJDK Java 1.6.0
- Centos 5.5 x32

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  Eclipse recommends Java 1.5 or greater.

I haven't had any problems running Eclipse with OpenJDK.

Answer (score 0):

I personally wasn't able to get eclipse working with the Open JDK and had to install the Sun JDK. I'm on Kubuntu 11.04.